# Extjs throws error "please verify that the file exists"

Tags: javascript, extjs

I started to learn ExtJS but i have some problems loading view file.
When i refresh my browser i'm getting following errors in my console.

```
ext-dev.js:10454 GET http://bugtracker.com/app/views/Login.js?_dc=1461346272737 Ext.apply.injectScriptElement @ ext-dev.js:10454Ext.apply.loadScriptFile @ ext-dev.js:10577Ext.apply.require @ ext-dev.js:10769(anonymous function) @ ext-dev.js:11123Ext.apply.doProcess @ ext-dev.js:7453Ext.apply.process @ ext-dev.js:7442Ext.Class.ExtClass @ ext-dev.js:7359Ext.ClassManager.create @ ext-dev.js:8685Ext.apply.define @ ext-dev.js:9508(anonymous function) @ Application.js?_dc=1461346272723:1
ext-dev.js:10857 Uncaught Error: [Ext.Loader] Failed loading 'app/views/Login.js', please verify that the file exists
```

This is my Login.js controller

```
Ext.define('BugTracker.controller.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    views: ['Login'],
    init: function(){
        this.control({
            'login form button#submit': {
                click: this.onButtonClickLogin
            },
            'login form button#cancel': {
                click: this.onButtonClickCancel
            },
            'login form': {
                beforeaction: this.onFormBeforeAction
            }
        })
    },

    onButtonClickCancel: function (button, e, option) {
        button.up('form').getForm().reset();
    },

    onButtonClickLogin: function (button, e, option) {
        button.up('form').getForm().submit({
            url: '/login',
            failure: function(form, action){
                switch (action, failureType){
                    case Ext.form.action.Action.CLIENT_INVALID:
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Invalid login details');
                        break;
                    case Ext.form.action.Action.SERVER_INVALID:
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', action.result.msg);
                        break;
                    case Ext.form.action.Action.CONNECT_FAILURE:
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Server connection error');
                        break;
                    default:
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Error','An unknown error has occurred');
                }
            },
            success: function(form, action){
                user = Ext.create('BugTracker.model.User', action.result.user);
                button.up('login').close();
                Ext.create('BugTracker.view.Viewport');
            }
        })
    }
});
```

And this is my Login.js view

```
Ext.define('BugTracker.view.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.login',
    autoShow: true,
    height: 170,
    width: 360,
    layout: {
        type: 'fit'
    },
    iconCls: 'key',
    title: 'Login',
    closeAction: 'hide',
    closable: false,

    items: [{
        xtype: 'form',
        frame: false,
        bodyPadding: 15,
        defaults: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            anchor: '100%',
            labelWidth: 60
        },
        items:[{
            name: 'user',
            fieldLabel: 'User'
        },{
            inputType: 'password',
            name: 'password',
            fieldLabel: 'Password'
        }],
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            dock: 'bottom',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'tbfill'
            },{
                xtype: 'button',
                itemId: 'cancel',
                iconCls: 'cancel',
                text: 'Cancel'
            },{
                xtype: 'button',
                itemId: 'submit',
                iconCls: 'login',
                text: 'Login'
            }]
        }]
    }]
});
```

and this is my Application.js

```
Ext.define('BugTracker.Application', {
    name: 'BugTracker',

    requires: ['BugTracker.views.Login'],

    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

    views: [
        // TODO: add views here
    ],

    controllers: [
        // TODO: add controllers here
    ],

    stores: [
        // TODO: add stores here
    ],

    init: function () {
        Ext.apply(Ext.data.validations, {
            customPassword: function (val, field) {
                return /^((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{8,50})/.test(val);
            },
            customPasswordText: 'Not a valid password. Length should be between 6 and 65 chars. Password should contain one digit, one lovercase letter and one uppercase letter' +
            'and one special symbol (@#$%)'
        });
    },

    launch: function(){
        Ext.widget('login');
    }
});
```

Can you please help me what i'm doing wrong.
If you need any addition information's please let me know and i will provide.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found where is my problem.
The problem is in Application.js where i require views instead of view!

```
Ext.define('BugTracker.Application', {
    name: 'BugTracker',

    requires: ['BugTracker.view.Login'],

    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
    ...
```

Comment: It should have been easy to spot, the error says it's trying to load `app/views/Login.js`

Comment: jep, i saw it imidietly once i posted a question. Wheel it's my first time doing something in ExtJs and i think its quite complicated. Had to get grip on it